# why pyarrow ipc so slow?

Tags: python, numpy, ipc, pyarrow

I want to send a numpy from one process to another process,then I use python function

```
import numpy as np
import time
import ctypes

from multiprocessing import sharedctypes

data = np.ones([1, 1, 544, 192], dtype=np.float32)

capacity = 1000 * 1 * 544 * 192 * 10

buffer = sharedctypes.RawArray(ctypes.c_uint8, capacity + 1)
ndarray = np.ndarray((capacity,), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=buffer)

cur_offset = 0

t = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)
    data_size = data.shape[0]
    ndarray[cur_offset:data_size + cur_offset] = data
    cur_offset += data_size
e = time.time()

print(e - t)
```

get time cost 0.09337258338928223s

then I use pyarrow

```
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import time
import os

data = np.ones((1, 1, 544, 992), dtype=np.float32)

tensor = pa.Tensor.from_numpy(data)

path = os.path.join(str("./"), 'pyarrow-tensor-ipc-roundtrip')
mmap = pa.create_memory_map(path, 5000000 * 1000)

s = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    result = pa.ipc.write_tensor(tensor, mmap)
e = time.time()

print(e - s)

output_stream = pa.BufferOutputStream()

s = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
    result = pa.ipc.write_tensor(tensor, output_stream)
e = time.time()

print(e - s)
```

and get results:
1.8259341716766357s
3.7164011001586914s

why pyarrow ipc is so slow?Does it use share memory to communicate between different processes?

Comment: Is there any python ipc function faster than multiprocessing. sharedctypes? tks